# Rename a list with value of another one

Tags: c, linked-list, rename

I try to implement a program written in C language where I've got two linked list and I need to create a third one in which there are all the values of the first list eventually renamed with the values of the second one based on them order. Any of the value in updated third list should not  repeat ,it should return error.

Look at the example given below to understand how this program works:

### Ex.1

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
B = [e, f]
```

The third one will be:

```
C = [e, f, c, d]
```

### Ex.2

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
B = [a, e]
```

The third one will be:

```
C = [a, e, c, d]
```

### Ex.3

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
B = [c, d]
```

This should return an error because C will be

```
C = [c, d c, d]
```

but it can't have duplicate values.

### Ex.4

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
B = [b, a]
```

This shouldn't return any error because C will be

```
C = [b, a, c, d]
```

(there are not duplicate values and the first two elements of the list A will be renamed with the first two elements of the list B).

Below you can find how my idea looks like but I'm interested about different solutions of this problem

```
T //Temp
C //Result

for (int i = 0; i < |A|; i++) 
{
    if(i > length of B && T is not empty)
    {
        //One or more elements were not been renamed
        return ERROR
    }

    if(A[i] == B[i])
    {
        C[i] = B[i];
    }
    else
    {
        C[i] = B[i];

        if(T contains A[i])
        {
            pop A[i] from T
        }
        else
        {
            push A[i] in T
        }
    }

}
```

## EDIT

Background: this algorithm supports the creation of an alias table (C) from a concrete table (A) given a list of filed names (B).

- each list/table cannot contain duplicate values.
- length of B is less or equal than length of A (I can't rename more values of those I've got)

Comment: What is your desired output in the case of
    `A = [a, b, a, d]`
    `B = [b, a]`
?

Comment: Are you insisting on linked lists? looks suitable enough for arrays.

Comment: I've specified that neither A nor B contains duplicate values (this assumption is a-priori)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm writing a SQL-like language and at this moment I'm performing the semantic analysis of this construct. In semantic analysis I have to walk my concrete tree and it's simpler think those nodes  as a part of a  linked list rather than elements of an array (but if will be necessary I could "convert" them).

Comment: So you problem is reducing to building a new list with `B` elements first and then `A` elements without first `len(B)` elements. Or `C=concat(B, A[len(B)..])`. What is the problem? A simple loop will do.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Your solution doesn't work in any case, but it's interested. I could use your method to perform a temporary list and then verify if it doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: @SamueleColombo Oh, missed the part about not containing dupes in the result. But yes, you can do it, and you should think of effective way to do it..

Comment: Do you assume that `length(B) <= length(A)`? If not, what would `C` look like? Example: `A=[a], B=[b,c]` would `C` be `[b]` or `[b,c]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be easily done in Python. Something like this:

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    if len(list2) > len(list1):
        raise ValueError("list2 cannot be of greater length than list1")
    list3 = list(list1)  # make copy of list1
    list_after_overlap = list1[len(list2):]  # get slice of list1 starting from end of list2
    index = 0
    for item in list2:
        if item not in list_after_overlap:
            list3[index] = item
        else:
            raise ValueError("merged list would have repeated values")
        index += 1
    return list3
```

This isn't just Python showing off, although it is arguably a better tool for this job. This also reads nicely like pseudo-code, and having prototyped and tested our algorithm, we can implement the same logic in C, we just need some helper functions.

As it's been indicated, a simple array would do, and since you haven't specified the data type in your question, we'll use a plain old int:

```
merged_list_t merge_lists(const list_t list1, const list_t list2)
{
    merged_list_t result;
    result.merged_list.list_length = 0;
    result.merged_list.values = NULL;
    if (list2.list_length > list1.list_length)
    {
        result.error = ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED;
    }
    else
    {
        result.merged_list.values = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(list1.list_length));
        result.error = (result.merged_list.values == NULL) ? ERROR_MEMORY : ERROR_NONE;
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        replicate_list(&result.merged_list, list1, list2.list_length);
        list_t list_after_overlap = get_list_slice(list1, list2.list_length);
        for (size_t index = 0; index < list2.list_length && result.error == ERROR_NONE; index++)
        {
            if (!item_in_list(list2.values[index], list_after_overlap))
            {
                result.merged_list.values[index] = list2.values[index];
            }
            else
            {
                result.error = ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES;
                free(result.merged_list.values);  /* we won't be needing this anymore */
                result.merged_list.values = NULL;
                result.merged_list.list_length = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, the algorithm is essentially the same, with an improvement. In the python code we were copying the entire list1, only to then overwrite the overlapped values, which is a waste that could be meaningful on large lists. Now we only get the part after the overlap, which starts after list2, and use it for testing for duplicates. Here is the complete code, with a hack on main for some basic testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    ERROR_NONE,             /* success */
    ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES,  /* merged list would have repeated values */
    ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED,   /* second list length exceeds that of first list */
    ERROR_MEMORY            /* could not allocate memory for the merged list */
} error_t;

typedef struct {
    int *values;         /* pointer to int array that contains the list values */
    size_t list_length;  /* the number of elements in the list (array) */
}list_t;

typedef struct {
    list_t merged_list;       /* has pointer (values) to merged list (array), which MUST be freed */
    error_t error;            /* indicates success or the error code of the merge operation */
}merged_list_t;

typedef enum {FALSE=0, TRUE=1} bool_t; /* use stdbool.h preferably, if available */


/* === Test Utility functions */
static void print_list(const list_t list)
{
    putchar('[');
    for (size_t index = 0; index < list.list_length; index++)
    {
        printf("%d", list.values[index]);
        if (index < list.list_length - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}


static void print_merged_list(const merged_list_t list)
{
    if (list.merged_list.values != NULL && list.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        print_list(list.merged_list);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (list.error)
        {
        case ERROR_NONE: printf("Merged list is null (empty)\n"); break;
        case ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED: printf("Error: Length of list2 is greater than length of list1\n"); break;
        case ERROR_MEMORY: printf("Error: Unable to allocate memory for result\n"); break;
        case ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES: printf("Error: Merged list would have duplicate entries\n"); break;
        default: printf("Unexpected or unhandled error\n"); break;
        }
    }
}


/* utility functions */
static void replicate_list(list_t *new_list, const list_t list, size_t start)
{
    for (size_t index = start; index < list.list_length; index++)
    {
        new_list->values[index] = list.values[index];
    }
    new_list->list_length = list.list_length;
}


static list_t get_list_slice(const list_t list, size_t start_index)
{
    list_t sliced_list;
    if (list.values != NULL && start_index < list.list_length)
    {
        sliced_list.values = list.values + start_index;
        sliced_list.list_length = list.list_length - start_index;
    }
    return sliced_list;
}


static bool_t item_in_list(int item, const list_t list)
{
    bool_t in_list = FALSE;
    for (size_t i=0; i < list.list_length && !in_list; i++)
    {
        in_list = (item == list.values[i]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
    return in_list;
}


/* 
    Produces a merged list which consists of list1 replaced by the overlapping elements of list2,
    as long as the resulting list does not cause elements of the merged list to be repeated.
    Input:
        list1[]: int array of arbitrary length consisting of unique elements
        list2[]: int array of length smaller than of list1 consisting of unique elements
    Returns:
        A merged_list_t structure containing the merged list structure (which MUST be freed) and its length
        or an error code if the lists are of invalid length or the merge operation produces duplicate values
 */
merged_list_t merge_lists(const list_t list1, const list_t list2)
{
    merged_list_t result;
    result.merged_list.list_length = 0;
    result.merged_list.values = NULL;
    if (list2.list_length > list1.list_length)
    {
        result.error = ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED;
    }
    else
    {
        result.merged_list.values = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(list1.list_length));
        result.error = (result.merged_list.values == NULL) ? ERROR_MEMORY : ERROR_NONE;
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        replicate_list(&result.merged_list, list1, list2.list_length);
        list_t list_after_overlap = get_list_slice(list1, list2.list_length);
        for (size_t index = 0; index < list2.list_length && result.error == ERROR_NONE; index++)
        {
            if (!item_in_list(list2.values[index], list_after_overlap))
            {
                result.merged_list.values[index] = list2.values[index];
            }
            else
            {
                result.error = ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES;
                free(result.merged_list.values);  /* we won't be needing this anymore */
                result.merged_list.values = NULL;
                result.merged_list.list_length = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


void main(void)
{
    printf("Testing basic scenario\n");
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a2[] = { 6, 7 };
    list_t l1;
    l1.list_length = sizeof(a1) / sizeof(a1[0]);  /* get number of elements */
    l1.values = a1;

    list_t l2;
    l2.list_length = sizeof(a2) / sizeof(a2[0]);
    l2.values = a2;

    merged_list_t ml = merge_lists(l1, l2);
    print_list(l1);
    print_list(l2);
    print_merged_list(ml);
    free(ml.merged_list.values);

    printf("Testing merge with duplicate values\n");
    int a3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a4[] = { 4, 6, 8 };
    list_t l3;
    l3.list_length = sizeof(a3) / sizeof(a3[0]);  /* get number of elements */
    l3.values = a3;

    list_t l4;
    l4.list_length = sizeof(a4) / sizeof(a4[0]);
    l4.values = a4;

    merged_list_t ml2 = merge_lists(l3, l4);
    print_list(l3);
    print_list(l4);
    print_merged_list(ml2);
    free(ml2.merged_list.values);

    printf("Testing list2 with value from list1\n");
    int a5[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a6[] = { 3, 6, 9 };
    list_t l5;
    l5.list_length = sizeof(a5) / sizeof(a5[0]);  /* get number of elements */
    l5.values = a5;

    list_t l6;
    l6.list_length = sizeof(a6) / sizeof(a6[0]);
    l6.values = a6;

    merged_list_t ml3 = merge_lists(l5, l6);
    print_list(l5);
    print_list(l6);
    print_merged_list(ml3);
    free(ml3.merged_list.values);

    _getch();
}
```

But you specifically asked for linked lists, so to finally answer your question, here is one way to do it:

```
merged_list_t merge_lists(const list_t list1, const list_t list2)
{
    merged_list_t result;
    list_t list_after_overlap;
    initialize_list(&result.merged_list);
    if (list2.list_length > list1.list_length)
    {
        result.error = ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED;
    }
    else
    {
        bool_t success = replicate_list(&list_after_overlap, list1, list2.list_length);
        result.error = (success) ? ERROR_NONE: ERROR_MEMORY;
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        for (list_item_t *item = list2.head; item != NULL && result.error == ERROR_NONE; item = item->next)
        {
            if (!item_in_list(*item->value, list_after_overlap))
            {
                /* duplicate each item and append to merged_list */
                bool_t success = append_list_item(&result.merged_list, new_list_item(*item->value));
                result.error = success ? ERROR_NONE : ERROR_MEMORY;
            }
            else
            {
                result.error = ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES;
                destroy_list(&list_after_overlap);
                destroy_list(&result.merged_list);
            }
        }
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        /* join overlap with difference */
        result.merged_list.tail->next = list_after_overlap.head;
        list_after_overlap.head = result.merged_list.head;
        result.merged_list.tail = list_after_overlap.tail;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Again, same logic, the merge function and friends were just refactored to deal with linked lists. Here is the full code:

```
/* Enable debug heap functions (Visual Studio) */
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


typedef enum {
    ERROR_NONE,             /* success */
    ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES,  /* merged list would have repeated values */
    ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED,   /* second list length exceeds that of first list */
    ERROR_MEMORY            /* could not allocate memory for the merged list */
} error_t;

typedef struct list_item_ {
    int *value;  /* pointer to single value */
    list_item_ *next;
    list_item_ *previous;
}list_item_t;

typedef struct {
    list_item_t *head;
    list_item_t *tail;
    size_t list_length;
}list_t;

typedef struct {
    list_t merged_list;   /* linked list with result, MUST be freed */
    error_t error;        /* indicates success or the error code of the merge operation */
}merged_list_t;

typedef enum {FALSE=0, TRUE=1} bool_t;


/* === Test Utility functions === */
static void print_list(const list_t list)
{
    putchar('[');
    for (list_item_t *item = list.head; item != NULL; item = item->next)
    {
        printf("%d", *item->value);
        if (item->next != NULL)
        {
            printf(", ");  /* add comma if it's not the last item (tail) */
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}


static void print_merged_list(const merged_list_t list)
{
    if (list.merged_list.head != NULL && list.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        print_list(list.merged_list);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (list.error)
        {
        case ERROR_NONE: printf("Merged list head is null (empty list)\n"); break;
        case ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED: printf("Error: Length of list2 is greater than length of list1\n"); break;
        case ERROR_MEMORY: printf("Error: Unable to allocate memory for result\n"); break;
        case ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES: printf("Error: Merged list would have duplicate entries\n"); break;
        default: printf("Unexpected or unhandled error\n"); break;
        }
    }
}


/* helper functions */
static void initialize_list(list_t *list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->list_length = 0;
}


static list_item_t* new_list_item(int value)
{
    list_item_t *item = (list_item_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_item_t));
    if (item != NULL)
    {
        item->value = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (item->value != NULL)
        {
            *item->value = value;
            item->next = NULL;
            item->previous = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            free(item);
            item = NULL;
        }
    }
    return item;
}


static bool_t append_list_item(list_t *list, list_item_t *item)
{
    bool_t success = TRUE;

    if (item == NULL)
    {
        success = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            /* first item, set as head and tail */
            list->head = item;
            list->head->next = NULL;
            list->head->previous = NULL;
            list->tail = item;
        }
        else
        {
            /* item (new tail) will be preceded by the current tail */
            item->previous = list->tail;
            /* link current tail to new item */
            list->tail->next = item;
            /* make item the new tail */
            list->tail = item;
            list->tail->next = NULL;
        }
        list->list_length++;
    }
    return success;
}


static bool_t set_list_values(list_t *list, const int *values, size_t values_length)
{
    bool_t success = TRUE;
    initialize_list(list);
    for (size_t index = 0; index < values_length && success; index++)
    {
        list_item_t *item = new_list_item(values[index]);
        success = append_list_item(list, item);
    }
    if (success)
    {
        list->list_length = values_length;
    }

    return success;
}


static void destroy_list(list_t *list)
{
    list_item_t *next_item = NULL;
    for (list_item_t *item = list->head; item != NULL; item = next_item)
    {
        next_item = item->next;
        free(item->value);
        item->value = NULL;
        free(item);
        item = NULL;
    }
    list->list_length = 0;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}


static bool_t replicate_list(list_t *new_list, const list_t list, const size_t start)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    list_item_t *item;
    bool_t success = TRUE;

    initialize_list(new_list);
    for (item = list.head; item != NULL && success; item = item->next, count++)
    {
        /* skip items before start */
        if (count >= start)
        {
            /* create new list with remaining items */
            success = append_list_item(new_list, new_list_item(*item->value));
        }
    }
    if (!success)
    {
        destroy_list(new_list);
    }

    return success;
}


static bool_t item_in_list(int item, const list_t list)
{
    bool_t in_list = FALSE;
    for (list_item_t *l_item = list.head; (l_item != NULL) && !in_list; l_item = l_item->next)
    {
        in_list = (item == *l_item->value) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    return in_list;
}


/* 
    Produces a merged list which consists of list1 replaced by the overlapping elements of list2,
    as long as the resulting list does not cause elements of the merged list to be repeated.
    Input:
        list1[]: a linked list of arbitrary length consisting of unique elements
        list2[]: a linked list of length less than or equal to the length of list 1, also with unique elements
    Returns:
        A merged_list_t structure containing the merged linked list (which MUST be freed) and its length
        or an error code if the lists are of invalid length or the merge operation produces duplicate values
 */
merged_list_t merge_lists(const list_t list1, const list_t list2)
{
    merged_list_t result;
    list_t list_after_overlap;
    initialize_list(&result.merged_list);
    if (list2.list_length > list1.list_length)
    {
        result.error = ERROR_LENGTH_EXCEEDED;
    }
    else
    {
        bool_t success = replicate_list(&list_after_overlap, list1, list2.list_length);
        result.error = (success) ? ERROR_NONE: ERROR_MEMORY;
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        for (list_item_t *item = list2.head; item != NULL && result.error == ERROR_NONE; item = item->next)
        {
            if (!item_in_list(*item->value, list_after_overlap))
            {
                /* duplicate each item and append to merged_list */
                bool_t success = append_list_item(&result.merged_list, new_list_item(*item->value));
                result.error = success ? ERROR_NONE : ERROR_MEMORY;
            }
            else
            {
                result.error = ERROR_REPEATED_VALUES;
                destroy_list(&list_after_overlap);
                destroy_list(&result.merged_list);
            }
        }
    }

    if (result.error == ERROR_NONE)
    {
        /* join overlap with difference */
        result.merged_list.tail->next = list_after_overlap.head;
        list_after_overlap.head = result.merged_list.head;
        result.merged_list.tail = list_after_overlap.tail;
    }

    return result;
}


void main(void)
{
    printf("Testing basic scenario\n");
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a2[] = { 6, 7 };
    list_t l1;
    set_list_values(&l1, a1, sizeof(a1) / sizeof(a1[0]));
    list_t l2;
    set_list_values(&l2, a2, sizeof(a2) / sizeof(a2[0]));

    print_list(l1);
    print_list(l2);
    merged_list_t ml = merge_lists(l1, l2);
    print_merged_list(ml);
    destroy_list(&l1);
    destroy_list(&l2);
    destroy_list(&ml.merged_list);


    printf("Testing merge with duplicate values\n");
    int a3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a4[] = { 4, 6, 8 };
    list_t l3;
    set_list_values(&l3, a3, sizeof(a3) / sizeof(a3[0]));
    list_t l4;
    set_list_values(&l4, a4, sizeof(a4) / sizeof(a4[0]));

    print_list(l3);
    print_list(l4);
    ml = merge_lists(l3, l4);
    print_merged_list(ml);
    destroy_list(&l3);
    destroy_list(&l4);
    destroy_list(&ml.merged_list);


    printf("Testing list2 with value from list1\n");
    int a5[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a6[] = { 3, 6, 9 };
    list_t l5;
    set_list_values(&l5, a5, sizeof(a5) / sizeof(a5[0]));
    list_t l6;
    set_list_values(&l6, a6, sizeof(a6) / sizeof(a6[0]));

    print_list(l5);
    print_list(l6);
    ml = merge_lists(l5, l6);
    print_merged_list(ml);
    destroy_list(&l5);
    destroy_list(&l6);
    destroy_list(&ml.merged_list);
    printf("Try printing empty list...\n");
    print_merged_list(ml);

    /* print memory leak report (Visual Studio)*/
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    _getch();
}
```

Notice the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() macro if you are using Visual Studio, very handy for detecting memory leaks. Of course, if you are lucky to be running Linux just get rid of that and use Valgrind instead. On my system, it was clean.

Here is a sample of the output produced by main:

> Testing basic scenario
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [6, 7]
>
> [6, 7, 3, 4, 5]
>
> Testing merge with duplicate values
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [4, 6, 8]
>
> Error: Merged list would have duplicate entries
>
> Testing list2 with value from list1
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [3, 6, 9]
>
> [3, 6, 9, 4, 5]
>
> Try printing empty list...
>
> Merged list head is null (empty list)